# Является ли число простым

Tags: c++

Хочу написать прогу на C++. Она сначала просит ввести число (простое оно или нет, прога проверяет), потом выводит результат на консоль. Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать или хоть намекните (среда dev-c++ 4.9.9.2), очень прошу.

Answer (score 11):

Написать что-то в виде

```
int n;
// ввести n c клавиатуры

for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        // вывести, что n  не простое, так как делится на i
        return 0;
    }
}
//вывести что n простое. 
return 0;
```

Алгоритм, конечно, можно заметно ускорить, как минимум в два раза, но для начала хватит.

Comment: должно быть i<=sqrt(n), иначе квадрат простого числа тоже будет простым.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, даже лучше набросить сверху единицу, то есть `i<sqrt(n)+1`, а то вещественные числа не принято на равенство сравнивать.
Также, можно проверять делимость на 2 и дальше по нечетным числам.
А ещё я когда то делал так, вначале проверял 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, а потом, запускал цикл по числам вида `12n+1, 12n+5, 12n+7, 12n+11` - ускорение в 3 раза. Этого было достаточно, чтобы выиграть время на одной из олимпиад.

Comment: Поправь ответ? И ещё нехорошо на каждой итерации квадратный корень считать.

Answer (score 2):

А можно проверять делимость по простым числам...
А найти их в не очень большом количестве особого труда не составит... =)

Решето Эратосфена (до корня из n). За 1 секунду находит числа до 10^7 примерно...

А дальше перебор делимости (Либо если число уже найдено Эратосфеном, то и перебирать не придётся) на простые числа, если число больше чем 10^7 также до корня из n...

И всё довольно просто и быстро =)

Answer (score 1):

Довольна старая тема, но всё же добавлю. Есть одна особенность простых чисел - при возведении числа в квадрат, деление этого числа в квадрате на 24 будет давать остаток 1  ( c 2 и 3 не работает, т.к они слишком маленькие , но с остальными числами работает отлично и не тратит много ресурсов для проверки)

```
int isprime(int num)
{

    if ((num * num) % 24 == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

 return false;

}
```

Comment: И не только простых, но и составных, что делает данный алгоритм непригодным для определения простых чисел

Comment: Это не работает с составными числами, только с простыми.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMkIiFs35HQ

Comment: 25, 35, 49, 55, 65, 77, 85, 91, 95 и ещё бесконечное количество чисел, которая ваша функция определяет как простые

Comment: Плюс к тому, кроме 2 и 3, с простого числа 46349 и последующие простые числа определяет как составные

Answer (score 0):

В плане эффективности могут намекнуть, например, на тест Рабина-Миллера, но судя по всему, Вам будет проще реализовать проверку тривиальным делением

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
bool prime(ll n) {
    for (ll i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: И правильно минуснули. Зачем в цикле проверять делимость на четные?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, i;
    bool isPrime = true;
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    for (i=2; i<=(sqrt(abs(n))); i++){
        if (n%i==0){
        isPrime = false;
        break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime)
        cout<<"This is a prime number"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"This is not a prime number"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Это готовый код

Answer (score -1):

В первом ответе допущена неточность!!!
Я бы написал так

---

```
bool prostoNumer(int n){
    for (int i = 2; i<=sqrt(n); i++) 
        if (n % i == 0) 
            return false;   
    return true; 
}
```

---

PS: дело в том что пропускает 4. Потому что цикл не работает sqrt(4) == 2, 2 < 2 и поэтому цикл завершает работу с ложным результатом. нужно поправить 2 <= 2

Comment: Это есть в комментариях под принятым ответом

Answer (score -1):

Обратите внимание на класс `Prime`. Простое число - число, имеющее два делителя. Это единица и само это число. Следовательно единица простым числом являться не может, так как она имеет один делитель, значит ее нужно исключить. Для этого воспользуемся условным оператором `if`. После этого начнем искать делители этого числа (будем перебирать все числа, которые меньше указанного числа), напомню делителем называется число, которое делится на данный делитель без остатка, то есть остаток равен 0. Когда нашли такое число, ставим на него булевое значение false, как пометка о том, что данное число является составным. После выполнения управляющей конструкции `for` остаются некоторые числа, которые не помечены false, то есть не имеют делителя(отличного от себя и 1), помечаем их как true.

```
namespace one
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Prime prime = new Prime();

            int AmountOfNumbers = 10;

            for (int i = 2; i < AmountOfNumbers; i++)
            {

                if (prime.IsPrime(i))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " простое число.");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " составное число.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Prime
    {

        public bool IsPrime(int x)
        {
            if (x > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
                {
                    if ((x % i) == 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код рабочий, но _слишком_ неоптимальный, даже по сравнению с предыдущими ответами