# Определение простоты числа. В очередной раз

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа

Нужно узнать, является ли число простым. Попробовал взять первое решение отсюда ([Является ли число простым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54193/%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC)) и запихнуть его в свой код, но тогда получается, что 1 - простое, 4 - простое, а это не так. Пожалуйста, не нужно сложных алгоритмов, которые якобы увеличивают производительность, не до этого мне сейчас.
Я хочу понять, почему не работает мой код (пропускает 4ку, например). А т.к. код брал у того автора, интересно, почему его ответ в плюсе.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    bool simple = true;
    int n;

    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n == 1) simple == false;
        if (n % i == 0) {
        simple = false;
        return 0;
        }
    }
    if (simple)
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Цитирую комментарий с того же ответа: `должно быть i<=sqrt(n), иначе квадрат простого числа тоже будет простым.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, давайте разберем ваш код...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    bool simple = true;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
```

Пока все логично.

```
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
```

Итак, если `n` - квадрат простого числа (кстати, где `#include <math.h>`?), то это простое число не проверяется (оно же не меньше, а равно корню квадратному). Например, для 4 этот цикл выполнен не будет, т.к. 2 *не меньше* 2.

```
        if (n == 1) simple == false;
```

Если `n` - единица, сравниваем `simple` и `false`. Зачем - непонятно.

```
        if (n % i == 0) {
            simple = false;
            return 0;
        }
```

Если `n` делится на `i`, присваиваем `simple` значение `false` и завершаем программу.

```
    }
```

Цикл закончен. `simple` ни разу не менялось (там, где менялось - тут же программа завершается), так что оно равно `true`. Значит, код

```
    if (simple)
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит просто `YES`, даже без перевода каретки. Код с выводом `NO` никогда не выполняется.

Код разобран? Почему не работает - вопросов больше нет?

Comment: Я понял! Спасибо огромное за детальный разбор, все по полочкам разложил себе, теперь можно задаваться вопросом, как сделать это быстрее :)

Comment: Кстати, в VS 15 sqrt работал без подключения. Но когда залил на сайт для проверки - ошибка компиляции. Обидно.

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый :) А быстрее - можно начать с проверки только нечетных. или тех, которые имеют вид `6n+1` или `6n-1` (2 и 3 проверять отдельно). Условие цикла я вы переписал как `i*i <= n`. Еще быстрее - по крайней мере хотя бы какой-то кусок таблицы простых чисел если не на ходу просчитывать, то просто прошить в программе...

Answer (score 3):

Раз у вас цикл начинается с 2

```
for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
```

то по крайней мере 1 сразу же следует исключить из простых чисел. Также не имеет смысла проверять для четных чисел, являются ли они простыми или нет. Поэтому в цикле достаточно рассматривать в качестве делителей нечетные числа.

В этом цикле

```
for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n == 1) simple == false;
    if (n % i == 0) {
    simple = false;
    return 0;
    }
}
```

некорректное условие цикла `i < sqrt(n)`. Должно быть по крайней мере `i <= sqrt(n)`. В начале цикла каждый раз происходит лишняя проверка переменной `n` на равенство 1. И кроме того происходит непонятный выход из программы.

Используйте следующий подход

```
int n;

scanf_s("%d", &n);

bool prime = n == 2 || (n % 2 && n != 1);

for (int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2)
{
    prime = n % i;
}
```

Вот простая демонстрационная программа, показывающая данный подход

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
        bool prime = n == 2 || (n % 2 && n != 1);

        for (unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2)
        {
            prime = n % i;
        }

        if (prime) std::cout << n << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```